# Table embeded in TD with COLSPAN messing up parent TABLE

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a table where you click on the row to see more detail.  The detail is an embedded table using a colspan.  This should take up the full width.  What ends up happening is that the embedded table forces first col to the width of the embedded table.

This is the initial look.

```
NAME1 AMOUNT PURPOSE
NAME2 AMOUNT PURPOSE
NAME3 AMOUNT PURPOSE
```

Now click on the first row, and I expect to see the following where the embedded table takes up all the columns.

```
NAME1 AMOUNT PURPOSE
 VENDOR KIND AMOUNT DETAIL
 VENDOR KIND AMOUNT DETAIL
 VENDOR KIND AMOUNT DETAIL
NAME2 AMOUNT PURPOSE
NAME3 AMOUNT PURPOSE
```

This is what I am seeing in both chromium and firefox.

```
NAME1                       AMOUNT PURPOSE
 VENDOR KIND AMOUNT DETAIL
 VENDOR KIND AMOUNT DETAIL
 VENDOR KIND AMOUNT DETAIL
NAME2                       AMOUNT PURPOSE
NAME3                       AMOUNT PURPOSE
```

I could really use some help in trying to have the first column keep its width when the embedded table is shown.  If you remove the style='display:none', it initially displays as expected.  However, once you cycle through the show/hide toggle it displays incorrectly.  Here is a sample.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<style>
.hidden { display: none; }
.money  { text-align: right; }
td {
padding-left:1em;
}
</style>
<script language="javascript">
function show_hide(elmid){
elm = document.getElementById(elmid);
if (elm.style.display=="none") {
    elm.style.display = "inline";
}
else {
    elm.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Reimbursement</h1>
<p>Click on 'D. Smith' or anywhere in the first row to see detail.</p>
<table>
<tr><th>Who</th><th>Amount</th><th>Purpose</th></tr>
<tr onclick="show_hide('exp47')"><td>D. Smith</td><td class='money'>37.61</td><td>Treats &amp; Snacks</td></tr>
<tr id='exp47' style='display:none'>
  <td colspan='3'>
  <table><thead>
    <tr><th>Vendor</th><th>Kind</th><th>Amount</th><th>Detail</th></tr>
  </thead><tbody>
    <tr><td>Dollar Tree</td><td>food</td><td>3.00</td><td>teddy bear cookies [3]</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Dollar Tree</td><td>tax</td><td>0.05</td><td>1.50%</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Sams</td><td>supplies</td><td>10.07</td><td>Lysol 3 pac</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Sams</td><td>supplies</td><td>6.98</td><td>hand sani</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Walmart</td><td>food</td><td>6.98</td><td>pf bulk gf</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Walmart</td><td>food</td><td>3.58</td><td>gm cereal</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Walmart</td><td>food</td><td>2.42</td><td>gv h4y rice</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Walmart</td><td>food</td><td>4.44</td><td>gv ff sticks [3]</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Walmart</td><td>tax</td><td>0.30</td><td>1.75%</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Jewel</td><td>food</td><td>6.00</td><td>glbl cookies 10z [6]</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Jewel</td><td>tax</td><td>0.14</td><td>2.25%</td></tr>
  </tbody></table>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Another</td><td class='money'>?.??</td><td>Another</td></tr>
</table></body></html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your javascript:

```
elm.style.display = "inline";
```

Inline display is a no-no for tr - table row - tag.

The right thing to do is set display to "table-row":

```
elm.style.display = "table-row";
```

You can read more about that here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html
By the way, you should consider adding a jsFiddle for these kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
    elm.style.display = "inline";
```

Is the wrong display type. Change to

```
    elm.style.display = "table-row";
```

And all should be fine. May not work on older IE browsers, though.

http://jsfiddle.net/YuEyp/